# bash:variable with double quotes

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I am a newbie to bash script programming and when I learned the variable expansion I amd puzzled by the variable.
1.when I want to define a variable,I can do as following:

```
name=foo
name="foo"
name='foo'
```

what's the difference between themm?
2.when I want to print a variable,I can do as following"

```
echo $name
echo "$name"
echo "$(name)"
```

3.I also encounter the part as following:

```
name=$(date)
```

what the "()" do,why it can resolve the command?

I googled my question and read some docs,eg (http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3898896/Single-vs-Double-Quotes-in-Bash.htm) but i am still puzzling,can anyone explain it clearly?

Comment: (3) is called "command substitution". See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Comment: (2) - `echo $name` splits the contents of `$name` into words, expands globs, and passes each word as a separate argument to `echo`. Thus, it changes newlines into spaces, and replaces a `*` surrounded by spaces with a list of files in the current directory. `echo "$name"`, by contrast, emits the precise contents of `$name`, **unless** it's a value that `echo` is inherently broken for and unable to handle (for many implementations of `echo`, `-n` and `-E` are such values). If you want something that works like `echo`, but is always correct, `printf '%s\n' "$name"` is the safe and portable bet.

Comment: (1) - they're all identical in the use case given here. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more general documentation.

Comment: (0) - I'm commenting, not answering, because this a *collection* of questions, not a single, focused question suitable for inclusion in StackOverflow's knowledgebase. Also, several of the items in the collection are duplicate of things other people already asked -- so if you asked them one at a time, they could be closed as duplicate with a link to the canonical existing question, but being a single question with a bunch of unrelated things as it is, the only valid close reason is "too broad".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks,I read your wiki and know the difference between them.also,I will notice the question I asked next time.

Comment: ...to be clear, by the way, assignment context implicitly disable string-splitting and glob expansion, which is why `foo=$bar` doesn't require quoting to be correct, but `echo "$bar"` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name=foo` since the value is not present inside quotes, it won't accept the value which has spaces like `name=foo bar`

`name='foo'` this won't expand the text present in the value. That is `foo $bar` would be read as literal `foo $bar`. It won't expand `$b`

`name="foo"` values within the double quotes would be parsed or expanded.